# How to delete values above a defined gap in data (Excel)?

Tags: excel, vba

I will appreciate any help regarding the following issue:

I have data set which was distributed to - time, symbol and price using the Pivot function. My data set have gaps within it which prevent me to run few calculations using python. I'll need to find a way to delete all the values above these gaps (taking in to consideration that the gap is bigger then 3 cells). It's a big file (2566 rows × 1642 columns) so doing it manually will be painstakingly time consuming effort.  I have highlighted the gaps using conditional formatting but I can't see a feature that will allow me to delete all values above them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion , instead of deleting the cells fill it with 0 value that might help you get the correct calculations. You can auto fill the blank spaces with 0 from the fill option available in Home section in column of AutoSum , Fill and Clear.

Comment: Hi, I thought about it as well, but it will mess the calculations of the values in the final output as it will add the 0 values in the formula, but it will not if the value is blank (NaN). Thank you for the suggestion though!